# Bootstrap datepicker : text not legible; How to change background color?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I use `bootstrap-datepicker3` from a gem, his [Github of bootstrap datepicker](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails)

But I use a black bootstrap theme and I don't know how to isolate or change the background color of the datepicker window... It seems to take the background color of the main bootstrap theme.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Dates</span>
    <div class="input-group" id="datepicker">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="date_start" data-behaviour='datepicker'>
      <span class="input-group-addon">à</span>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="date_end" data-behaviour='datepicker'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

[image: Example]

I tried a solution but it's for datetimepicker and it doesn't work..

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try overriding the background-color in your CSS:

```
.datepicker.dropdown-menu {
  background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, I can to change the color text but not the background. There is something that overwrites the `.datepicker.dropdown-menu` background-color.

Comment: Can't comment on your answer, but one suggestion to the * could be table, maybe?

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me.  My datepicker currently appears as shown in this [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/vjLMIQr.png).  I'm using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateLastRidden, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", type = "date", data_autoclose="true", data_todayBtn="linked", data_todayHighlight="true" })` to create the datepicker.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
  <style type="text/css">
      .datepicker.dropdown-menu table  {
          background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
  </style>
```

it works !

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by following the steps provided in the following thread, with one change.  I used the ".datepicker .table-condensed" selector.

[Reduce size and change text color of the bootstrap-datepicker field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404620/reduce-size-and-change-text-color-of-the-bootstrap-datepicker-field/19856004#19856004)