# is there any way to customize bootstrap linked picker calendar using css?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am doing my FYP in which i need help to customize the calendar colour using CSS.
I am new to bootstrap linked picker[image: This is the Image and I want to change the colours of calendar.].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Use F12 tools to check the object and manipulate its CSS properties.

2- Apply the desired CSS using jquery [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)  after showing the picker using javascript (because it will not load plain CSS in code, must be set using javascript & jquery after creating the popup everytime)

Comment: Can you please show me or share some useful link for this.

Comment: https://www.jquery-az.com/bootstrap-datepicker-set-up-guide-with-8-online-demos-and-code/ and http://jsfiddle.net/apougher/UdePB/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35740274/how-to-change-bootstrap-datepickers-selected-date-color-background