# bootstrap daterangepicker, create calendar with custom colors for each days

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using this script:
https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker
It's very simple and fine, now I want to see in the calendar built any days in highlighted, the color must be custom, so I can see 
availability in the period I'm going to select, such as a HeatMap...

Comment: Here's someone overriding the background color of the calendar by [hijacking the `onShowDatePicker` event](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19856004/3585500). It's a start...

Answer (score 1):

The author of the script helps me to find the solution using the option **isCustomDate: (function)** of the script, here's a sample use

```
isCustomDate: function(date) {
    var ratio_0=['2017-09-15','2017-09-16','2017-09-17'];
    var ratio_1=['2017-06-15','2017-06-16','2017-06-17'];
    var ratio_2=['2017-07-15','2017-07-16','2017-07-17'];
    var ratio_3=['2017-08-15','2017-08-16','2017-08-17'];
    if ($.inArray(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), ratio_0) > -1) {
        return 'ratio_0';
    } else if ($.inArray(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), ratio_1) > -1) {
        return 'ratio_1';
    } else if ($.inArray(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), ratio_2) > -1) {
        return 'ratio_2';
    } else if ($.inArray(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'), ratio_3) > -1) {
        return 'ratio_3';
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

the funcion returns a custom class for the specified dates for use it via css.